# React internet explorer 11 rendering the result of mapping over an Immutable collection error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs, webpack, immutable.js

I have a problem with mapping Immutable array objects in React in internet explorer 11.

For example I have response from service an array:

```
array = [{title: 'Hello world'}, {title: 'Night view'}]
```

I convert this array to immutable in reducer and store it. Then in `TitlesContainer`, in render method try to iterate through items:

```
render () {
  const { array } = this.props
  return (
    <ul>
      {array.map((item, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>{item.get('title')}</li>
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

All works fine, in Chrome, Opera, Firefox. But in internet explorer 11 I have got this error:

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: List [ [object Object], [object Object] ]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `TitlesContainer`.

In `webpack.config.js` I have included `babel-polyfill` to module enrty because of IE11, it throws 'Promise is not defined' before this. It fix promise problem but problem with iteration in immutable array still exists.

There is workaround to use `array.toJS().map` instead of `array.map` but I  think there must be a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try return `<li>` in '()', as you do with `<ul>`:

```
render () {
  const { array } = this.props
    return (
      <ul>
        {array.map((item, index) => {
          return (<li key={index}>{item.get('title')}</li>)
      })}
      </ul>
    )
```

}

You can also try to use shorthand:

```
{array.map((item, index) => (<li key={index}>{item.get('title')}</li>)};
```

Also please make key of `<li>` more unique. Without this, react can't check of exact change in this element. F.e. make `key={'name_of_my_list' + item.get('id)}` (if you have id of course ;))

Comment: Thanks, I've try both, but this don't work for me. I have also checked that `console.log(item.get('title'))` working well. The problem is with rendering. It can't render `<li>{item.get('title')</li>`...

Comment: One more important thing: which version of React do you use? React v0.12.x only accepts pure arrays, not Immutable Lists.

Comment: I'm using v0.14.x and in some projects v15.3.x ... result is same. The problem is working in Internet Explorer. In Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari all works fine.